# JQM Datepicker not showing in popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker, datebox

I have following piece of code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="datePicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jqm.js"></script>
    <script src="datePicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

    <title>Popup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#popup" data-rel="popup">Show popup</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popup">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Popup</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <label>Time:</label>
                <input name="time" id="time" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useNewStyle":true, "overrideTimeFormat": 24, "overrideTimeOutput": "%k:%M", "themeButton": "a", "themeInput": "a", "theme": "a", "themeHeader": "a", "closeCallback": "vypoctiTrvani"}' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I click on the clock icon in my popup (the datepicker icon) nothing appears.

This happens to me only when using Datepicker inside a popup.

I tried setting z-index to high numbers, but it didn't work.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide it in codepen or jsfiddle. So easily to identify issue

Comment: unfortunately, this is unsupported - DateBox uses the popup widget for it's own display, and they are not nest-able.  DateBox can be used inline in another popup, but not as an additional dialog like this.